Google Docs Api Using Create Google Document And Add The Multiple Images
I am create the Google Document and Insert the Multiple Image but Can not Set the Positions how to fix it laravel using Google Docs API
I am Expecting the add the InsertInlineImage Set Position that is i want to expected
    public function createGoogleDocSheet(Request $request) 
    {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAuthConfig('../resources/google/service_account.json');
        $client->setApplicationName('Google Docs API');
        $client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Docs::DOCUMENTS,\Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE]);

        $service = new \Google_Service_Docs($client);

        $document = new Google_Service_Docs_Document(array(
            'title' => "My Doc"
        ));
        $my_document = $service->documents->create($document);
        $document_id = $my_document->documentId;

        $requests[] = new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
            'insertInlineImage' => array(
                'uri' => 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/productlogos/docs_2020q4/v6/web-64dp/logo_docs_2020q4_color_1x_web_64dp.png',
                'location' => array(
                    'index' => 1,
                ),
                'objectSize' => array(
                    'height' => array(
                        'magnitude' => 50,
                        'unit' => 'PT',
                    ),
                    'width' => array(
                        'magnitude' => 50,
                        'unit' => 'PT',
                    ),
                    "offsetX"=> array(
                        "magnitude"=> 50,
                        "unit" => "PT",
                    ),
                    "offsetY" => array(
                        "magnitude" => 50,
                        "unit" => "PT",
                    ),
                ),
            )
        ));

        $requests[] = new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
            'insertInlineImage' => array(
                'uri' => 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/productlogos/docs_2020q4/v6/web-64dp/logo_docs_2020q4_color_1x_web_64dp.png',
                'location' => array(
                    'index' => 1,
                ),
                'objectSize' => array(
                    'height' => array(
                        'magnitude' => 50,
                        'unit' => 'PT',
                    ),
                    'width' => array(
                        'magnitude' => 50,
                        'unit' => 'PT',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            
        ));

        // Execute the requests.
        $batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array(
            'requests' => $requests
        ));
        
        $response =
            $service->documents->batchUpdate($document_id, $batchUpdateRequest);
       
        $userPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
            'type' => 'user',
            'role' => 'writer',
            'emailAddress' => 'Muthukumar.m@filmplace.co'
        ));

        $driveService = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
                    $driveService->getClient()->setUseBatch(true);

        $batch = $driveService->createBatch();

        $request = $driveService->permissions->create($document_id, $userPermission, array('fields' => 'id'));

        $batch->add($request, 'user');
        
        $results = $batch->execute();

        $data['document_id'] = $document_id;

        return response()->json([
            'status' => true,
            'status_message' => Lang::get('talent_messages.create_document_successfully'),
            'data' => $data,
        ]); 
        
    }

throw the error for "{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 400,\n    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"offsetX\" at 'requests[0].insert_inline_image.object_size': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"offsetY\" at 'requests[0].insert_inline_image.object_size': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"offsetX\" at 'requests[1].insert_inline_image.object_size': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"offsetY\" at 'requests[1].insert_inline_image.object_size': Cannot find field.",\n    "errors": [\n      {\n        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"offsetX\" at 'requests[0].insert_inline_image.object_size': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"offsetY\" at 'requests[0].insert_inline_image.object_size': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"offsetX\" at 'requests[1].insert_inline_image.object_size': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"offsetY\" at 'requests[1].insert_inline_image.object_size': Cannot find field.",\n        "reason": "invalid"\n      }\n    ],\n    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",\n    "details": [\n      {\n        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",\n        "fieldViolations": [\n          {\n            "field": "requests[0].insert_inline_image.object_size",\n            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"offsetX\" at 'requests[0].insert_inline_image.object_size': Cannot find field."\n          },\n          {\n            "field": "requests[0].insert_inline_image.object_size",\n            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"offsetY\" at 'requests[0].insert_inline_image.object_size': Cannot find field."\n          },\n          {\n            "field": "requests[1].insert_inline_image.object_size",\n            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"offsetX\" at 'requests[1].insert_inline_image.object_size': Cannot find field."\n          },\n          {\n            "field": "requests[1].insert_inline_image.object_size",\n            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"offsetY\" at 'requests[1].insert_inline_image.object_size': Cannot find field."\n          }\n        ]\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n"
how to fix it

About but Can not Set the Positions, where do you want to put the image into the document body? And, it seems that your tag related to the language is google-apps-script. You want to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
